# Data bus access in Intel 8086

Tags: microprocessor

I wonder how a multi-bytes instruction is executed when there is only 16-bit data bus? Assume the instruction is `MOV AX,[10H]`. The machine code of this instruction is 3 bytes. By combining the CS:IP registers, a 20-bit address is generated and there three bytes (which represents the machine code of that instruction) is accessed.

```
                 |           |
        CS:IP -> +-----------+
                 |    A0     |
                 +-----------+
                 |    10     |
                 +-----------+
                 |    00     |
                 +-----------+
                 |           |
```

As you can see, we have to put A01000 on the data bus.

Comment: I'm guessing it needs multiple cycles to fetch the whole instruction (if I'm understanding your question correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intel 8086 processor doesn't execute commands directly from data bus. Instead, commands at CS:IP are fed into 6-byte [prefetch queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086#Performance) and executed from there. This queue was specifically designed to accommodate a complete instruction, and the maximum instruction length on 8086 is limited to 6 bytes.

Comment: Yeah, bad phrasing. Certainly the instruction length was used to define the queue size, not the other way around.